# Performance em laços de repetição Java

Tags: java, desempenho, sintaxe, loop

Qual a diferença de perfomance entre os três tipos de laços destacados abaixo.

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    //CODE
}

for (Foo foo : list) {
    //CODE
}

Iterator<Foo> iterator = list.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    //CODE
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Antes de mais nada é preciso considerar que [muitos testes de desempenho estão errados](http://java.dzone.com/articles/why-many-java-performance-test). Fazer um *micribenchmark* não é tão simples quando executar os três códigos por diversos fatores internos e externos:

- Outros programas executando em segundo plano pode interferir diferentemente nos testes.
- Com vários testes numa mesma execução, um pode afetar os demais. Por exemplo, o primeiro teste pode ter instanciado elementos e o Garbage Collector é executado somente no segundo teste.
- O teste pode não refletir um contexto real de uso. No seu exemplo, você não inclui o acesso ao elemento. Como a resposta do Ricardo já mencionou, o gargalo de um laço `for` ou `while` usado para percorrer uma lista (`List`) pode estar no método `get()`, que faz verificação do índice acessado e então precisa recuperar o elemento do vetor interno. Entretanto, não posso concordar com a resposta dele, porque o `Iterator` também usa internamente o método `get()`.
- A JVM faz otimizações tanto no bytecode quanto durante a execução, podendo variar conforme a versão.
- O resultado varia grandemente para diferentes tipos de `Collection`s. [Esta resposta no SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1879292/1683070) diz não haver diferenças significativas.

O seu teste é muito parecido com [este benchmark](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/03/26/performance-comparison-of-different-for-loops-in-java/). Sem o acesso aos elementos, o resultado obtido pelo autor foi:

> For each loop :: 110 ms
>
> Using collection.size() :: 37 ms
>
> Using [int size = list.size(); int j = 0; j < size ; j++] :: 4 ms
>
> Using [int j = list.size(); j > size ; j--] :: 1 ms

Em resumo, um laço decrementando a variável é o mais rápido neste cenário e isso provavelmente se deve ao fato de que comparar uma variável a zero é mais eficiente.

O site Mkiong também [produziu um benchmark](http://www.mkyong.com/java/while-loop-for-loop-and-iterator-performance-test-java/). O resultado:

[image: Performance Test Result]

Entretanto, isso foi muito questionado. Veja os comentários para ver que pessoas diferentes obtiveram resultados diferentes em diferentes plataformas e com pequenas modificações no código.

Ao considerar a quantidade de código executado, o `Iterator` realmente parece ser o menos eficiente. Veja o código dos métodos `next()` e `hasNext()` do `Iterator` usado no `ArrayList`, extraídos do JDK 6:

```java
public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
    try {
    E next = get(cursor);
    lastRet = cursor++;
    return next;
    } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
    checkForComodification();
    throw new NoSuchElementException();
    }
}

public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size();
}
```

Note que os métodos `size()` e `get()` da lista são chamados de qualquer forma. Não existe uma mágica para recuperar o próximo elemento. Além disso, é feita uma verificação se a lista foi modificada por outro método. Ainda bem que isso é feito apenas comparando-se dois inteiros, mas a chamada ao método e a comparação acabam tendo algum impacto.

Enfim, através de uma **análise estática**, podemos afirmar que um laço `for` usando uma variável auxiliar (`i`) e um valor limite fixo, isto é, sem chamar `size()` a cada iteração é mais eficiente.

Na prática, porém, o cenário pode mudar drasticamente se o programador ficar com "preguiça" de atribuir o elemento a uma variável. Quem nunca viu algo como o exemplo abaixo?

```java
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if (list.get(i) != null) {
        list.get(i).metodo();
    }
}
```

Outro fator que pode mudar muito é se não usarmos o `ArrayList`. O `LinkedList`, por exemplo, possui complexidade `O(n)` para encontrar um elemento qualquer, pois ele precisa percorrer os elementos um a um até encontrar o elemento desejado.

E pensando ainda na qualidade de um software como um todo e não apenas na perspectiva do desempenho, laços `for..each` tem a grande vantagem de serem mais "limpos" (menos digitação, mais fácil entendimento) e menos propenso a erros (estouro de limite, iniciar contador em 1 ao invés de zero e assim por diante).

Outra observação importante, pensando na questão de desempenho, é que os maiores gargalos estão no acesso aleatório aos dados e na própria definição da estrutura de dados. Embora alguns considerem exagero a preocupação com esses detalhes, a verdade é que faz muita diferença escolher as estruturas adequadas para armazenar os dados. O conceito de que memória e CPU são "baratos" cai por terra assim que começamos a lidar com mais do que alguns milhares de registros, por exemplo. A escolha dos comandos para percorrer a estrutura definida vem como consequência das decisões já tomadas.

A **conclusão** é que não existe um laço definitivamente mais eficiente para todos os casos. A ênfase mais importante está em definir uma estrutura de dados adequados para cada caso, considerando o consumo de memória e a complexidade de acesso a um elemento específico daquela estrutura.

Answer (score 2):

Usar o `Iterator` e o "`foreach`" não vai causar nenhum problema de performance, já que eles possuem velocidades parecidas ao percorrer *collections*. O mesmo não pode-se dizer para o `for` normal. O problema está no acesso via índice `get(i)` pelo `for` que degrada a velocidade do loop.

No [SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113216/which-is-more-efficient-a-for-each-loop-or-an-iterator) tem uma boa e completa resposta sobre isso. Além disso, os diferentes tipos de implementações da `List` e seus respectivos usos podem causar melhora (ou piora) de performance, como é o caso de `ArrayList` ou `LinkedList`.